# User Access Permissions

Tags: filesystems, freebsd, file-sharing

I have recently taken ownership of a (FreeBSD) FileServer and need to identify which shares users have access to on an individual basis.

Is there an easy way to achieve this with a single command?

Comment: FreeBSD is no more linux than OSX is.  It's clear you are new to "unix like" operating systems -- are you aware of the concept of file ownership and permissions?  It could be that all you are looking for is `ls -l`.

Comment: If the FreeBSD box is running NFS(Network File System) then you are exporting shares. In the `exports` file you have defined the access to these shares.

Comment: @goldilocks Well, considering how often people refer to "the MS-DOS prompt" or "a MS-DOS window" at least in Windows 7...

Answer (score 1):

I think that an answer to your general question, cannot be as satisfying as you wish. You can see the exports (shares) of the server using

`cat /etc/exports`

> Each line in /etc/exports specifies a file system to be exported and
>   which clients have access to that file system, as well as any access
>   options as documented here: http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/network-nfs.html

If you want a really easy to use and manage solution for a file server, in my opinion is to use freeNAS: http://www.freenas.org/ which is based on freeBSD too.

Maybe it's a pain to make the transition but if you are the one who will manage this server, you 'll got less pain on management.